# App installed but not appearing

Tags: android, android-studio, installation, apk

I am developing an Android app. At first everything was going smooth, but after some time, the app started to disappear (more accurate not appear) after a successful installation on a real android device. After installing it, the open button is deactivated (I can only click done) and I cannot find it on the menu, but checking with root uninstaller, it appears that the app is really installed.

On the emulator, it installs ok but the installed app doesn't show the correct icon, while prior to this error it wasn't doing so.

I forced the removal of some permissions @ Manifest, because I only need (and the app was running with it only) internet access (web view). I tried removing that but it is just the same.

This change came when I introduced a splash screen which loads after the webview if it's the first time ==> MainActivity: If it's first time { setContentView with splash layout. Eventually, after the 3 slides, button onClick which changes to webview activity (class)(1) } else { setContentView with webview layout(2) }

(1) and (2) perform the same tasks, (2) inside a method in MainActivity and (1) in the onCreate of the WebView class.

I know for a fact that it is a better way to do this. Any help on how to do perform this task in a better way appreciated, and also how to get rid of the "installed but invisible" thing.

Comment: Can you paste you manifest ?

Comment: I think that the issue is due to the Manifest, not to Activities. Paste it if you can, please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your manifest ensure that your intent filter has the category `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

```
<activity 
        android:name=".activity.SpashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: That was it! I actually read your comment, looked at it and it was it. The MainActivity had launcher category, but the main action was put in one of the acitivities :)